# Mil-Std Style Section Numberings (With automatic reference number generation and TOC)

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm trying to create a document that is structured like a Mil-Std, such as this:
[image: Scope Applicable Docs Lorem Ipsum]

I could use a list for this, however I don't want to give up the automatic TOC building, figure numbering, index generation, etc.

There is a Mil-Std style on CTAN, but it has an unknown license so I'd prefer not to use it (also it's from 1991 and doesn't seem to have any other documentation).

I am currently using a `report` documentclass, which generates "Chapter " \n "Scope" rather than this kind of index.

Looking at ["Tex Catalog Online: Alternate Classes"](http://www.tscm.com/MIL-STD-464.pdf)

[2](http://www.tscm.com/MIL-STD-464.pdf): http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#classes "Tex Catalog Online: Alternate Classes", it looks like "anonchap" is close, but it doesn't quite have the formatting.

Does somebody know how to go about this while keeping LaTeX's ability to build an index/TOC/figure numbering?

[Edit] For those who haven't seen a Mil-Std before, here is an example:
[Mil-Std 464](http://www.tscm.com/MIL-STD-464.pdf)
And Wikipedia on MilSpecs: [Wikipedia: United States Military Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Military_Standard)

Comment: Since not everbody is familar with `Mil-Std` you should give us more information on this style

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the note; info added in the edit!

Comment: I've added a possible 'starter' and removed the `indexing` tag since that tag is related to the real `index`. I think you really mean `numbering` and `sectioning`

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the headers of `Chapters` etc. can be tedious. Either use `titlesec` or patch the relevant `\@makechapterhead` etc. and `\@sect` commands as well as `\l@section` to provide the correct spacings and features. (I've changed the `\l@section` command to allow left-aligned section numbers in ToC.)

Basically, the `section` style seems to be similar what `\paragraph` does: A (numbered) title with text following without vertical spacing in between.

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\raggedright}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{20pt}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{20pt}


\newif\ifusedot
\usedottrue


\newcommand{\usedot}{%
  \ifusedot
  .%
  \fi
}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{3.5em}}

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
  \begingroup
  #6{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
    \interlinepenalty \@M #8 \@@par}%
  \endgroup
  \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \bfseries%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \bfseries%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
    \fi
    \@xsect{#5}
  }

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \Huge\bfseries \thechapter\usedot\ 
    \nobreak
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}



\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}



\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{Scope}
\section{Proposition}
\blindtext
\chapter{Applications}


\end{document}
```

[image]